# Python Key Error on Column Names When Trying to Merge DFs

Tags: python, pandas, merge, keyerror

i have two DFs ('coeff' and 'ncDatam') and I'm trying to merge them on a shared column name but I'm getting a KeyError on the column name 'plant_name'. Here is my Df "coeff":

```
coeff.columns
Out[66]: Index(['plant_name', 'slopex', 'intercept'], dtype='object')
coeff.head(5)
Out[67]: 
      plant_name    slopex    intercept
0  BII NEE STIPA  1.095434 -1278.741489
1  DOS ARBOLITOS  1.161407 -3438.054141
2         PIER B  0.819827  3352.473727
3        PIER II  0.906328   903.044250
4        PIER IV  0.987371  4850.368353
```

And, here is the DF 'ncDatam':

```
ncDatam.columns
Out[63]: Index(['plant_name', 'year', 'month', 'power_kwh'], dtype='object')
ncDatam.head(5)
Out[68]: 
      plant_name  year  month  power_kwh
0  BII NEE STIPA  1991      1   11905.83
1  BII NEE STIPA  1991      2   15084.93
2  BII NEE STIPA  1991      3    7823.63
3  BII NEE STIPA  1991      4    4417.25
4  BII NEE STIPA  1991      5    2987.07
```

And, here is my tragic command that provides the "KeyError" that is baffling to me. Thank you for your help. It appears that clearly the column name 'plant_name' is found in both DFs:)

```
df = ncDatam.merge(coeff, on='plant_name') 

df = ncDatam.merge(coeff, on='plant_name')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-69-9cba791972e8>", line 1, in <module>
    df = ncDatam.merge(coeff, on='plant_name')

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7297, in merge
    validate=validate,

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 86, in merge
    validate=validate,

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 627, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 983, in _get_merge_keys
    right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))

  File "C:\Users\U321103\Anaconda3\envs\Stats\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1692, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'plant_name'
```

Here is how I created the DF coeff:

```
coeff = output.reset_index()
print(coeff)
coeff.columns.values[1]= "slopex"
coeff.columns.values[0]= 'plant_name'
           index     Slope     intercept
0  BII NEE STIPA  1.095434  -1278.741489
1  DOS ARBOLITOS  1.161407  -3438.054141
2         PIER B  0.819827   3352.473727
3        PIER II  0.906328    903.044250
4        PIER IV  0.987371   4850.368353
5       SANTIAGO  0.395098  21697.674121
6      VENTA III  1.069942  -1924.804108
7        VENTOSA  0.986452  -1926.409407
```

Here is how I created the DF "ncDatam"

```
ncData.columns
Out[81]: Index(['plant_name', 'business_name', 'maint_region_name', 'power_kwh', 'dataset', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'], dtype='object')

ncDatam = ncData.groupby(["plant_name","year","month"])[["power_kwh"]].mean().reset_index().round(2)
```

Here is print of the data types of each column:

```
print(coeff.columns.to_series().groupby(coeff.dtypes).groups)
{dtype('float64'): Index(['slopex', 'intercept'], dtype='object'), dtype('O'): Index(['plant_name'], dtype='object')}

print(ncDatam.columns.to_series().groupby(ncDatam.dtypes).groups)
{dtype('int64'): Index(['year', 'month'], dtype='object'), dtype('float64'): Index(['power_kwh'], dtype='object'), dtype('O'): Index(['plant_name'], dtype='object')}
```

Comment: How is the Output you expect from merging those dfs?

Comment: Could you show how did you create the dataframes coeff and ncDatam?

Comment: I have added more context now with df creation.

Comment: I have read that my keys need to be the same or that the column names of "plant_name" need to be of the same data type??? I think that they are both strings..? Is this the problem?